# multiple cookies and one cookie with multiple key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, cookies

I encountered this function, it sets multiple key-value pairs within one cookie, but what if I want to set multiple cookies?

```
function setCookie(start_time,end_session_time,total_time,flag,count){
     document.cookie = "start_time="+start_time;;

    if(end_session_time) {
        document.cookie ="end_session_time="+end_session_time;
    }

    if(total_time){
        document.cookie ="total_time="+total_time;
    }
    if(flag){
        document.cookie ="flag="+flag;
    }
    if(count){
        document.cookie = "count="+count;
    }

    console.log("document.cookie ="+ document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: It does set multiple cookies.

Comment: You're not right. This function set **multiple** cookies, not one cookie

Comment: but the `console.log` seemed to print one cookie...

Comment: @Blake This means that only one (first) parameter is passed to the function

Comment: not exactly, if you tested it, all the params are passed. see @jfriend00 's answer

Answer (score 1):

`document.cookie` is a bit odd.  When you read `document.cookie`, you get all the cookies that apply to the current domain/path in one giant string with separators between them.

When you set `document.cookie`, it adds or removes (depending upon the expiration date set) new values to the current domain/path's cookie storage without affecting the other cookie values that aren't specified.  You can add one new cookie value or many different cookie values at once with each assignment to `document.cookie`.  Usually, most utility functions that add cookies add them one at a time (just because it's simpler).

It's all described fairly well here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie